# camera not detected even though it works once in a while

Tags: pi-4, camera

I am a 3D enthusiast and I use my Raspberry Pi 4 for 3D printing with my Creality CR-10S Pro V2. I had successfully installed Klipper on my Raspberry Pi 4 and everything was functioning properly. My Logitech C920 camera was being recognized correctly, and I could view the video feed on my Klipper interface (Fluidd).

However, I encountered an issue after being prompted to update the operating system. Following the update, both the "vcgencmd get_camera" command in the terminal and the video feed on my interface stopped working. Additionally, the light on my webcam also turned off.

After making several adjustments, I managed to sporadically restore the camera feed on my interface (Fluidd). This process is inconsistent: the camera doesn't work when I start the Raspberry Pi and requires changing settings (back and forth) and attempting multiple times before the video feed is restored. I even attempted to detect the camera in the terminal, while seeing the feed I had managed to appear, by using the "vcgencmd get_camera" command, but it consistently reports "supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0," despite the fact that I am still able to see the video feed.

The frustrating part is that I need to manipulate the settings (changing them and then reverting back) for the camera to function, but this method is not reliable and doesn't work every time.

Could you please assist me in troubleshooting and resolving this issue?

**EDIT :**
thank you for your answer.
Here a photo to help picturing the problem.
[image: 3d printer interface (FLUIDD) with terminal PUTTY at the same time]

The settings I was talking about are from FLUIDD, wich is installed on my rasberry pi with KLIPPER. It is an interface to completely control my 3Dprinter. (speed, webcam, objects to print, leveling...).
There is a plugin to that interface who is called crowsnest, that alow you to acces your webcam to make timelapses for exemple or acces to your camera through streaming. I need to purposefully choose some bad settings and then revert to the good ones (multiple times) until the camera turn on. (so the settings are on the software side, and then refresh the page multiple times)

As you can see on the photo, my camera is turned on but the line in PUTTY that @dougie gave me return no camera available!
I forgot to mention that my webcam works with the usb port.(and not the pins)

**EDIT 2 :**

```
user@mypi:~ $ libcamera-hello
Preview window unavailable
[1:10:58.750836949] [5737]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.5+                83-bde9b04f
[1:10:58.794922492] [5738]  WARN V4L2 v4l2_pixelformat.cpp:328 Unsupported V4L2                 pixel format H264
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***
```

**EDIT 3 :**
[image]

with that my webcam is detected...
so, is it coming from the software ???

Comment: Use `libcamera-hello --list-cameras` to see your camera. That old vcgencmd stuff is out of date now.

Comment: `I need to manipulate the settings` ... what settings? ... please edit your post with info .... do not add comment